# Postman Interceptor for another Chrome profile

Tags: google-chrome, postman

I've default chrome profile where I used Interceptor. But now I've created another profile in chrome where I do all development work.

But Interceptor is connecting to default profile only. I've tried removing and restarting postman. But it forces me to Install extension in default profile. While there is already interceptor running in another profile.

Is there a setting to switch Chrome profile in Interceptor or this is a bug in Postman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misunderstood this concept. Every new profile you create on chrome, you have to install extension separately. and that extension will connect only with that chrome profile.

So I was confused because I had installed `postman` in both profile and both are using same credentials, and both chrome profile have `postman-intercepter` installed. And was trying to connect one instance with other intercepter.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still confused about this.
This may help you

1. close all browser
2. open the browser with desired Chrome profile
3. now you can start intercept any HTTP request

as mentioned above, postman interceptor can only connect to one Chrome addon which is the one you open first